# How to set an icon for the DownloadManager Request?

Tags: android

I'm trying to set an icon for the DownloadManager request that I created, but I can't manage to do that.
I read about creating a BroadcastReceiver, but I was wondering if it's possible to do that without it.
This is my code for the DownloadManager Request:

```
final String filename = getIntent().getExtras().getString("id") + ".apk";

            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
            request.setTitle(filename);
            request.setDescription("Downloading...");
            request.setMimeType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            // in order for this if to run, you must use the android 3.2 to compile your app
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            }
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/Library", filename);
            // get download service and enqueue file
            DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            manager.enqueue(request);

            Toast.makeText(LinkActivity.this, "Download has started.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Here's an example of what it looks like now:
[image]

My target is to change the image of the notification ImageView on the left.

Thank you very much.

Comment: have u found any solution? or Marcin Orlowski is correct in the following answer

Answer (score 1):

You cannot override this icon. And, if I remember correctly, it would  make no much sense to be able to, as download manager can have more than one downloading running and it will still take one notification slot to indicate that...